"Revision <..> is not ready and cannot serve traffic" on Cloud Run deployment
I'm struggling on deploying a Nodejs app onto Google Cloud Run which is a rest api server written in Express. This app has been deployed to Cloud Run and has not update new revision for about one year. Lately I do some modification and want to deploy a new revision to Cloud Run but run into an error.
Revision <revision-name> is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable
here's the error message on GCP's Logging
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224328Z Error: Cannot find module '../config/firebase'
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224332Z Require stack:
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224339Z - /workspace/src/controller/floor.controller.js
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224344Z - /workspace/src/routes/floor.routes.js
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224350Z - /workspace/app.js
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224356Z at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1224:15)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224361Z at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050:27)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224366Z at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:19)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224371Z at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224403Z at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/src/controller/floor.controller.js:1:12)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224407Z at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1480:14)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224412Z at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1564:10)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224416Z at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:32)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224421Z at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:12)
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224426Z at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:19) {
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224431Z code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224437Z requireStack: [
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224442Z '/workspace/src/controller/floor.controller.js',
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224447Z '/workspace/src/routes/floor.routes.js',
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224452Z '/workspace/app.js'
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224457Z ]
DEFAULT 2024-05-14T04:11:14.224461Z }

the error message said that it can't find some modules in my source code. but it runs as expected when I test the server on my local environment ( and of course the missing module is there ).
my package.json file looks like:
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js",
    "deploy": "gcloud run deploy api --allow-unauthenticated --source=.",
    "local-serve": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
    "http2-express-bridge": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


What I tried

add "gcp-build":"" in packaged.json' script as suggested in this stackoverflow question but still get the same error.

{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js",
    "deploy": "gcloud run deploy api --allow-unauthenticated --source=.",
    "local-serve": "nodemon app.js",
    "gcp-build":""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  ...
}


follow the Troubleshooting guide, make sure that the server is listening on host 0.0.0.0 and environment variable PORT, but still not solve the problem.

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
...
...
...
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT}...`));

Had anyone encountered a similar situation? Any tips or suggestions are really appreciated!

After dedicating a day, I finally made it work by removing one line in my .gitignore file. this sounds silly but I didn't notice that the paths / files listed in .gitignore won't be pushed onto Cloud Run.
there's a line /src/config in my .gitignore so that all the files in this path are not pushed onto cloud. After removing this line in .gitignore, it works well again.

As stated in the Documentation your container must listen for incoming HTTP requests on the port that is defined by Cloud Run and provided in the $PORT environment variable.
If your container fails to listen on the expected port, the revision health check will fail, the revision will be in an error state and the traffic will not be routed to it. For example, in Node.js with Express, you should use:
// index.js
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Hello world listening on port', port);
});

// package.json
    "engines": {
        "node": "16.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },

Also have a look at this Stackoverflow Link by @FlightPlan, which explains clearly about the Port problem vs "the container won't start" problem. Check on the troubleshooting steps he shared.
There might be a possibility you may miss adding required dependencies in the package.json file. Make sure  to add all the dependencies that are compatible with the node version.
Sometimes it may take time to re-launch the procedure. Try to wait a few minutes and then just re-launch the procedure.

thanks for your reply! I do listen to the process.env.PORT as you mentioned without success. I have checked the dependencies in package.json  and it should be correct because I can run app locally. I don't read any environment variable except for &PORT in my project, so I guess it shouln't be environmental problem. I'll try to use Sentry to see if it can find the problem

after downloading the source code from Cloud Build page. I found out that 1 folder in my project is missing. this explains why it reports that some modules can't be found. I suspect the reason is because I'm deploying on Windows 11 VM on Mac. which is a ARM based machine. the Troubleshooting guide has notedIf you build your container image on a ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run.

Have you gone through the steps suggested in this Troubleshooting Documentation.
